# numpy.argmin for elements greater than a threshold

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy

I'm interested in getting the location of the minimum value in an 1-d NumPy array that meets a certain condition (in my case, a medium threshold). For example:

```
import numpy as np

limit = 3
a = np.array([1, 2, 4, 5, 2, 5, 3, 6, 7, 9, 10])
```

I'd like to effectively mask all numbers in `a` that are under the limit, such that the result of `np.argmin` would be 6. Is there a computationally cheap way to mask values that don't meet a condition and then apply `np.argmin`?

Comment: Could you explain why in your question you said np.argmin is 6? In this case it would be 0. If you masked all the numbers less than 3, then you'd get [4,5,5,3,6,7,9,10]. The np.argmin of this is still not 6.

Comment: @OneRaynyDay My guess: the masked array the OP had in mind is `[--, --, 4, 5, --, 5, 3, 6, 7, 9, 10]`. Then the smallest element is 3, which is on position 6 (starting to count with 0) of the masked array. This is what happens in MaxPowers' answer.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You could store the valid indices and use those for both selecting the valid elements from `a` and also indexing into with the `argmin()` among the selected elements to get the final index output. Thus, the implementation would look something like this -

```
valid_idx = np.where(a >= limit)[0]
out = valid_idx[a[valid_idx].argmin()]
```

Sample run -

```
In [32]: limit = 3
    ...: a = np.array([1, 2, 4, 5, 2, 5, 3, 6, 7, 9, 10])
    ...: 

In [33]: valid_idx = np.where(a >= limit)[0]

In [34]: valid_idx[a[valid_idx].argmin()]
Out[34]: 6
```

Runtime test -

For performance benchmarking, in this section I am comparing the [`other solution based on masked array`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37973394/3293881) against a *regular* array based solution as proposed earlier in this post for various datasizes.

```
def masked_argmin(a,limit): # Defining func for regular array based soln
    valid_idx = np.where(a >= limit)[0]
    return valid_idx[a[valid_idx].argmin()]

In [52]: # Inputs
    ...: a = np.random.randint(0,1000,(10000))
    ...: limit = 500
    ...: 

In [53]: %timeit np.argmin(np.ma.MaskedArray(a, a<limit))
1000 loops, best of 3: 233 µs per loop

In [54]: %timeit masked_argmin(a,limit)
10000 loops, best of 3: 101 µs per loop

In [55]: # Inputs
    ...: a = np.random.randint(0,1000,(100000))
    ...: limit = 500
    ...: 

In [56]: %timeit np.argmin(np.ma.MaskedArray(a, a<limit))
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.73 ms per loop

In [57]: %timeit masked_argmin(a,limit)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.03 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 11):

This can simply be accomplished using numpy's `MaskedArray`

```
import numpy as np

limit = 3
a = np.array([1, 2, 4, 5, 2, 5, 3, 6, 7, 9, 10])
b = np.ma.MaskedArray(a, a<limit)
np.ma.argmin(b)    # == 6
```

Comment: why not `b.argmin()` ?

Comment: Another possibility: `b = np.ma.masked_less(a, limit)`.